# Can I specify site after I have built the deployment package with Microsoft Web Deploy?

Tags: .net, web-deployment, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

Currently I do the following:

1. Create package using

   msbuild something.csproj /P:Configuration:Some /T:Package
2. After that I go to the Package folder under obj\Some\Package and run the following

   something.csproj.deploy.cmd /y /M:https://mydeployservice /u:user /p:password --allowUntrusted /A:Basic

Everything works fine, but I wonder how do I specify the site which I want the application installed to? Here I only define the service/server, and the name of the site is from the deploy command. Is it possible to use a parameter for the site name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Web Deploy, it should be possible to use a parameter for the site name when you package the source, then specify a new site name when you deploy. Here are some articles that show how to use parameters:

- [Customizing a Deployment Package](http://blog.alanta.nl/2011/02/web-deploy-customizing-deployment.html)
- [Web Deploy Parameterization in Action](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html)
- [Web Deploy: Replace Rule vs. Parameterization](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2010/09/17/web-deploy-replace-rule-vs-parameterization.aspx)
- [Packaging and Deploying Web Applications for the Visual Studio Development Web Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/gg465162)
- [Team Build + Web Deployment + Web Deploy + VS 2010 = Goodness](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html)